# flutter appbar not showing in android

Tags: android, flutter, appbar

flutter appbar not showing in android when pushed page.
only showing gray background but it works button action.
when I touched button I can see a normal appbar for a second.
iOS is fine.
how can I fix it?

image is here

[image]

it is one of my appbar code

```
SearchAppBar(TextEditingController textController, BuildContext context,
  {String? text,
  bool showBack = true,
  List<Widget>? actions,
  Function? focusAction,
  Function? submitAction,
  Function? changeAction,
  Function? pressAction})
  : super(
        title: Container(
          height: 36,
          margin: showBack
              ? EdgeInsets.only(right: 16)
              : EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 0, 16, 0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
            color: FbColors.searchBackground,
          ),
          child: TextField(
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
            controller: textController,
            onTap: () async {
              focusAction!();
            },
            onChanged: (text) async {
              changeAction!(text);
            },
            onSubmitted: (value) async {
              submitAction!(value);
            },
            textInputAction: TextInputAction.search,
            textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(-6, 0, 0, 14),
              hintText: text ?? '',
              hintStyle:
                  TextStyle(fontSize: 15, color: FbColors.defaultText),
              icon: Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 14),
                child: Image.asset(
                  'assets/icons/search-small.png',
                  width: 14,
                ),
              ),
              suffixIcon: textController.text.length > 0
                  ? IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        pressAction!();
                      },
                      icon: new Image.asset(
                        'assets/icons/close-circle.png',
                        width: 18,
                      ),
                    )
                  : null,
              focusColor: FbColors.defaultText,
              focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent)),
              border: UnderlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent)),
              enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent)),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        backgroundColor: appBarBackground,
        toolbarHeight: appBarHeight,
        bottom: PreferredSize(
            child: Container(
              color: FbColors.lineGrey,
              height: 1,
            ),
            preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(1)),
        elevation: 0,
        leadingWidth: 42,
        titleSpacing: 0,
        leading: showBack
            ? new IconButton(
                splashColor: Colors.transparent,
                highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
                onPressed: () => {Navigator.pop(context)},
                icon: new Image.asset(
                  'assets/icons/arrow-back.png',
                  width: 9,
                ))
            : null,
        actions: actions);
```

flutter appbar not showing in android when pushed page.
only showing gray background but it works button action.
when I touched button I can see a normal appbar for a second.
iOS is fine.
how can I fix it?

Comment: elevation: 0, to shadowColor: Colors.transparent,

Comment: wrap your widget with scaffold and set you appbar inside scaffold